# HP ML350-G6 adding hot-swap drives

Tags: windows-server-2008, hp, hp-proliant

I have an HP Proliant ML350-G6 server with 3 600Gb hard drives on RAID5. It's running out of space so I'm adding 2 1Tb hard drives which I will configure as another volume on RAID1. My question is, do I need to switch off the server to put the new hard drives in or can I do it during normal office hours whilst users are working on it? Supposedly they are hot-swapable disks.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The disks are hot-swappable. There's no need to turn the server off.

You'll want to use the Smart Storage Administrator (SSA) tool to handle the new volume creation.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Much appreciated.